# Create list from pexpect expect data

Tags: python, pexpect

I haven't found any examples that are interacting with multiple lines of data. In the majority of examples, pexpect looks for a single value before returning or spawning.

For my situation, I'm expecting multiple lines and would like to append each to a list. I'm currently not able to figure out how to do so.

Here's what I have so far:

```
...
active_hosts = []

host_discovery = pexpect.spawn(nmap_scan)
active_hosts += pexpect.expect(substring)
...
```

The scan I'm running should output multiple lines of data. How am I able to capture each line an append to my list?

```
limited@kali:~# nmap blah blah blah
host1
host2
host3
```

Hoping to have [host1, host2, host3] when the timeout or EOF is reached.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you really need `pexpect` for this? If you just want to get the output of `nmap blah blah blah` you're much better off with Subrocess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen('nmap_command',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
output = child.communicate()[0]
# do your stuff with output
```

for more on subprocess look here:[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)